# QStackedWidget (Qt) в C# (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, form

Есть ли аналог QStackedWidget (Qt) в C# (.Net)?

Comment: А как выглядит этот `QStackedWidget`? Может приложите скриншот?

Comment: Если правильно понял что представляет из себя `QStackedWidget` то подобного в `Wpf` нету.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо:

```
addWidget(new QLabel("Page 1", this));
addWidget(new QLabel("Page 2", this));
addWidget(new QLabel("Page 3", this));
```

Вы можете использовать "Notebook" — вкладки, они же TabItem'ы:

```
ListBox notesList = new ListBox();

notesList.Items.Add("Элемент контента 1");
notesList.Items.Add("Элемент контента 2");
notesList.Items.Add("Элемент контента 3");

TabControl products = new TabControl();

products.Items.Add(new TabItem 
{ Header = new TextBlock { Text = "Page 1" }, Content = notesList});
products.Items.Add(new TabItem 
{ Header = new TextBlock { Text = "Page 2" }, Content = notesList});
products.Items.Add(new TabItem 
{ Header = new TextBlock { Text = "Page 3" }, Content = notesList});

products.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right;
```

Если хотите узнать больше, хороший учебник: http://metanit.com/sharp/wpf

Пробуйте, здесь подход несколько другой. Идентичного функционала увы нет.

Comment: В `Qt` есть `QTabWidget` - аналог `TabControl`. Полагаю, ответ можно дополнить тем, как добиться требуемого поведения.

Comment: Да, простите, чтобы  все работало нужно добавить.
TabControl products = new TabControl();
...
products.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right;
И будет вам счастье. Аналогично можно выставлять фиксированную длину кнопок, крутить их и т.д. Здесь Вам помогут Appearance и другие полезные свойства.